# java array of arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have four columns of buttons in my program. Buttons move between columns when assigned new ones. Instead of declaring 4 separate arraylists to store the buttons, is there a way to create 1 array of arraylists so I can simply itterate through the array?

I've tried     `List<JButton>[] lists = new ArrayList<JButton>[5];`

But that won't work. What am I missing?

EDIT:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if(choiceList.getSelectedIndex() == i){
                if(btnPersons[nameList.getSelectedIndex()].getX() == column[i]){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error - Name already present in the column.","", 1);
                }else{
                    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                        if(lists[j].get(i) != null){
                            lists[j].remove(btnPersons[nameList.getSelectedIndex()]);
                        }
                    }
                    lists[i].add(btnPersons[nameList.getSelectedIndex()]);
                    lists[i].get(i).setBounds(column[i], ROWS[i], 125, 20);
                    //reloadLocations();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my code currently.Once a new column is selected it checks to see which listthe button was in and removes it, then adds it to the new list. But my new problem is that using lists[i] will no longer work. Idk how to properly loop through my list of arraylists using this declaration:

```
List<ArrayList<JButton>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<JButton>>();
```

Comment: Hm, `List[] lists = new ArrayList[5];` compiles and works fine for me though I'd use generics and would make an array of List[5]. Perhaps the error is elsewhere. What was wrong with your code? What error messages do you see?

Comment: Please describe how it won't work. It should work.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what is "won't work"? This post seem interesting and could become a great one if you give more information.

Comment: Eclipse underlines the "new ArrayList<JButton>[5];" section and says: "Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList<JButton>"

Comment: While you aren't allowed to `new` a generic array, you are allowed to do this: `ArrayList<JButton>[] lists = (ArrayList<JButton>[]) Array.newInstance(ArrayList.class, 5);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to keep a list of lists of JButton objects:

```
List<List<JButton>> lists = new ArrayList<List<JButton>>();
// populate (replace with your code)
lists.add(Arrays.asList(new JButton("list 1, button 1"), new JButton("list 1, button 2")));
lists.add(Arrays.asList(new JButton("list 2, button 3"), new JButton("list 2, button 4")));
lists.add(Arrays.asList(new JButton("list 3, button 5"), new JButton("list 3, button 6")));
lists.add(Arrays.asList(new JButton("list 4, button 7"), new JButton("list 4, button 8")));

// iterate
for(List<JButton> subList : lists) {
    for(JButton button : subList) {
        System.out.println(button.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I create a for loop that could correspond to the list of lists. For example list[i] will not work...

Comment: try `for (JButton button : lists.get(i)) { // ...}`

Comment: Still no luck. I don't think I entirely understand I'm sorry.

Comment: If you want to loop/iterate the list of lists see the code in the answer. If you want to loop/iterate a speicla list, e.g. list no. 1 or 2 see the comment. I don't understand exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Giving an example of what worked for me / talked above.

```
    List []oArrayOfArrayList = new ArrayList[2];

    List<String> oStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> oIntegerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    oArrayOfArrayList[0] = oStringList ;
    oArrayOfArrayList[1] = oIntegerList ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create arrays from classes with generic parameters.

You'll either want to make a list of a list, or forgo generic parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to call the new operator for a generic object because at run time the type has been erased.

Answer (score 0):

create a class for your ArrayList:

```
    private class xxx extends ArrayList<JButton> {
        // need serial to keep IDE happy
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2392107594926751233L;
    };

    private xxx[] lists = new xxx[5];
```